# How to use UIViewController instead of UINavigationController in iOS

Tags: menu, uinavigationbar, slidetoggle

I am making slider menu view using [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) good appCoda tutorial.

There they used front view as UINavigationController. How can I use UIViewController only instead of UINavigationController? This image explains the problem.

[image: view]